# Does the maxLines option not apply for the legend on a Stacked Bar Google Chart at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm implementing a Stacked Bar Google Chart.  I have found that when my categories span more than one line and the legend is at the top, the legend will wrap to multiple lines, controlled by the maxLines option on the hAxis variable.

However, if I move the legend to the bottom, the legend no longer wraps, but gives a paged view of the categories.  This is the same behavior when the legend is on the top and the maxLines option is set to 1.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnPasquet/88g5c50L/).  The top graph has the legend on the top, and the bottom one has the legend on the top... I did that to make it easy...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 5, ''],
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 550,
        height: 160,
          chartArea: {height: '45%' },
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '55%' },
          hAxis: { maxValue: 100, ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100] },
        isStacked: true
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);

      var chart2 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));
    options.legend.position = "bottom";
      chart2.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Ugh... Just found this on Google's site:

> Maximum number of lines in the legend. Set this to a number greater
>   than one to add lines to your legend. Note: The exact logic used to
>   determine the actual number of lines rendered is still in flux.
>
> **This option currently works only when legend.position is 'top'.**
>
> Type: number Default: 1

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: but need a solution for multiline legends